# How to pass my own values to the view from controller in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have a view file `update.php` and contains the following code:

```
php foreach ($record as $my_records)

$val1=$my_records['name'];

$val2=$my_records['faculty'];

$val3=$my_records['level'];

$val4=$my_records['year'];

?>

php endforeach
```

And I have a controller with a function `update` and this controller gets the record from model like this:

```
$data['record']=$this->myproject_model->get_all_values($rollno);
```

and then pass those records on the view as follows

```
$this->load->view('iproject/update',$data);
```

But, I need to send my own values to the view from the controller. That is, I need to clear the data I got from model and send my own values to the view for some cases. So, how to put my own data in the `$data['record']` array and fetch those on in the view in the same way as shown in the above `update.php` code?

Comment: do u mean static data.............

Comment: yes, i want to pass static data..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send static data like this:

```
$data = array(
     'x' =>'hello',
     'y' =>'how are',
    );
```

You can send this `$data` array to the view as how you send `$data` previously and you can access it.

Answer (score 0):

You can always modify `$data['record']` in your controller after you fetch it from the model.

But the MVC way would be to send the correct data from the model itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
$records = $this->myproject_model->get_all_values($rollno);

$reults = $this->prepare_records($records); // Below.

$data['results'] = $results;
$this->load->view('iproject/update', $data);
```

And the function you need to write with your logic (easiest - but not best - place to put the function is in the controller.):

```
private function prepare_records($records)
{
  $results = array();
  // Fill up $results
  return $results;
}
```

An even better strategy would be to put the function in the myproject_model, to keep your controller clean and logic surrounding the data in the model.

You would replace:

```
$reults = $this->prepare_records($records);
```

with

```
$reults = $this->myproject_model->prepare_records($records);
```

And move the function to the model. You would need to change the declaration to public if it were in your model (which is cool, because now you can call it from whatever controller you want).

```
public function prepare_records($records) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would use a pointer in your foreach loop. Then you can check if the entry is something you need to modify, and then make the change.

In the following example, I check if users are in their 4th/Final year - if they are, we prepend 'Final Year Student - ' before their faculty's name. Instead of creating a new array and populating there, this is a more intelligent way of the code properly preparing the results for display.

```
foreach($records as &$record){
    if($record['year'] == '4'){
        $record['faculty'] = 'Final Year Student - ' . $record['faculty'];
    }
}
```

Now, once the loop is complete, $records will contain the modified entries.